# Trigger functions from another java program

Tags: java, swing

We've got a server app and two stand alone client apps (both with different functionality - one for front office and the other for back office). Everything is written in Java.

What we need right now:
If both apps are running - click on a button in one app -> checks to see if the other app is open and triggers some functionality (display a message, open a frame) on that app

if the other app isn't open -> it should display a message saying so.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this. The best real life example I can give is: how clicking on the an itunes link in the web browser opens the iTunes application if installed and to the relevant appstore page.

EDIT: Our applications don't deal with websites at all. Everything uses Swing.

Comment: IMO you'll need sth like simple Server-Client app. That means you'll have to edit first app to send data over the network to the second app and also you'll have to edit the second app to catch and parse data from network.

Comment: this might help you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: A lot depends on what the server is capable of doing.  Assuming you want to send a message from One PC to the server and then to the next.  This would require 1- That each PC could register with the server. 2- Each PC had some kind of callback mechanism that could allow the server to send messages to back to the client. 3- The server was capable of providing a list of connected clients.  All this comes down to how you are communicating with the server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "best" way to achieve inter-app communications but there are many ways; the best one will be the one that fits best your environment: network conditions, firewalls, number of calls, synchronous vs asynchronous, etc...

Usually communication is achieved using either:

- Remote Procedure Calls: an app basically calls a function/method on the other app and passes arguments. RPC are usually synchronous: the response is sent within the same communication/transaction
- Messaging: an app sends messages to the other app which, maybe, replies with other messages. Messaging is usually asynchronous.
  The frontier between the two can be pretty blur with some protocols like REST.

In the Java world,

- RPC is usually achieved using either

  - [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation): Java only solution; easy to implement; does not like firwalls much.
  - [SOAP Web services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP): not Java centric; hard to implement; full of traps; network friendly.
- Messaging can be achieved using

  - [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service): Java only; rather easy to implement but asynchronous; extremely powerful on high loads
  - JSON/XML HTTP/s Messaging: there are many protocols here from the most secure like [AS2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AS2) to RNIF, plain XML/Json POST etc... These are network and language agnostic but always require some work to implement.

An hybrid approach is [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) which has become very popular due to the benefits of an easy implementation and network friendliness but has the drawbacks of not being very formalized. it is a technology rather than a specification. I would look at documentation around [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) and frameworks like [Restlet](http://restlet.org/) and [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) to get you started.

(Edit)
I purposely did not mention developing your own with Java sockets. IO is by definition impure and often multithreaded: IO is *very* hard to get right. If you really insist going down that route, at least, use the help of a proper framework like Apache Mina or Netty.

Comment: I like the multi-approach proposed in this answer. Depending on the functional need, you could also add JMX. We use it on projects for monitoring, performance management, limited functionality triggering (start/stop components... )

Comment: Thank you for that detailed response BGR. We are infact already using JMS (activeMQ) to pass updates from the server to the client. Guess the existing infrastructure could be reused to pass messages between clients via JMS.