# How to display a JDialog on Host Side for a Server App

Tags: java, swing, remote-access, jdialog

Sure this will sound such a stupid question, though I do not know how to display a JDialog on host side.

We develop **an app** (appXXX, from now on) which, from time to time, **needs to be updated**. So we want it to be done **online**.

**To do so I am creating a Java application which will run on our server**, so **whenever there is an update to appXXX it will make a JDialog to appear on our customer's screens** (for what we will have their IP and ports, of course) to ask them whether we can proceed to update their systems or we should do it later on.

Dealing with JFrame, JDialog and company is not such a big deal. Although **what I do not know how to do is displaying and handling all these contents on the screen of a remote machine** (Applets may be? though I have seen their natural environment is a web browser, rather).

Simply that. Sorry if it looks like a silly question, though may be not quite so for Java newbies.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see the advantage of a java application for such a task. Applets are quite heavy and you need to integrate it in a web page. Why not directly display the message in a web page?

Comment: Another point (that could justify a java app on client side): has it to permanently run on background?

Comment: Furthermore, is your application appXXX a java application? if it is the case, why not use java web start on that purpose?

Comment: Thanks, C.Champagne.
Honestly, simply took Java because it is pretty widespread and is plenty with tutorials all around to learn anything I do not know how to do.

The application will run just when there are any updates, nowhen else. The idea is that programmers of the appXXX (not developed in Java) can start it so it runs all the updates on the customers' machines.

It will pose me the question too of finding out how to access their machines so the updating tool can run the SQL files on the clients hosts.

Comment: Yes how would you start this application remotely? Another question: you are telling it should execute SQL scripts. Has each client a local database?

Comment: It would be started by any of the developpers of the team who had completed some new feature to appXXX.

Then the process would start sending "isReachable" or the like messages to all customers, connecting with them as soon as they would be on reach, displaying the Dialog and, if accepted, it would start the execution of the SQL file on their local database (of which, yes, they would have one).

That's the whole idea

Comment: One question: I came across RMI 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation

while looking for solutions. Is this what I have to look on to do what is needed?

Comment: You need to have your remote application started.

Comment: See also this [overview](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17420349/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer coming from the comments. I think is is better to not post further comments on the question since it looks more like a chat ;-) but there are still many points that remain unclear, very unclear.

First I will suggest you to have look for deployment tools that might to what you intend out of the box. It could spare you some time.

If your clients work on windows machines, why not send them MSI file?

Anyway from what I understood, your update consist (among other?) of executing SQL scripts on a ***local*** embedded database.

If so,  [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation) could be a good and simple solution but you have to keep in mind that you will need to deploy your java app and its dependencies on all the clients and that is should be launched on startup.
You will also need a mechanism to to specify what can be executed and how.

You could also send a mail to the client with a link to either a page with an applet or better a link to your application deployed with [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/). Whatever the solution you chose among those two, you certainly will have to [sign](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html) your Jar in order to access local resources and jars.

There are certainly other (much better) solutions but more info would be nice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, Champagne.

Unfortunately, there is little more info about the app I can give you as, despite I had programmed in Java previously, it is the first time for me that I find myself involved in such a project - dealing with JDBC drivers, connecting with client machines, etc.

That's why all the ideas you put in your reply I find so valuable.

Comment: You are welcome. I still have one doubt: my answer is valid (concerning SQL scripts) if your DB is on the client and only accessible from there so you must execute it there. Otherwise I don't undestand why you would like to execute it on client machine.

Comment: Well, if I didn't misunderstand my boss, that's it.
Language is also a handycap, for my french is not so good, and I am new to Belgium, though I think that's it.